# How to make circular buttons with Font Awesome icons (and hover effect)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am trying to create buttons like the picture below.

[image: buttons]

I am using stacked Font Awesome icons to put the icons on top of a circle and it looks like this:

[image]

(Ignore the gray line at the bottom.  That's a result of poor screenshotting.)

However, as you can see, the icons are a tiny bit off.  Ideally, I want to push them up a bit so they are vertically centered in the circle and either make the circles bigger or the icons smaller to get the nice padding as in the example.  I also want to change the color of the circle which I don't know how to do and add hover effects (like change the icon to white).

Here is my code.

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
/>
<div class="row footer">
  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="copyright">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>

    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem here? because in above snippet icons are already in middle.

Comment: Hm...you're right.  But in the picture that I included, the icons are a bit off on my end.  Why is this?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out.  In my code, I was using Font Awesome 4.5.0 but the code snippet edit that was done by Paolo uses 4.7.0.  I changed it to that in my code and that fixed my centering issue.  Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem, you can use CSS `line-height`

```
span.fa-stack {
  line-height: 37px;
}
```

As for the second problem, you can apply `font-size` to FA icons, like this:

```
span.fa-stack > i:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 13px; /* Or whatever value looks best */
}
```

Or if you wanted, you could even use `transform: scale();` again:

```
span.fa-stack > i:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: scale(0.8); /* Or whatever value looks best */
}
```

For the `:hover` effect, you could use `transform: scale();`, which I belive is the best hover effect, along-side `cursor: pointer;`:

```
span.fa-stack:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3); /* Or whatever value looks best */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And for applying `color` to the circle, it's a simple as this:

```
span.fa-stack:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: #2D79AF; /* Or whatever color looks best */
}
```

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  align-items: center;
}
span.fa-stack:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
span.fa-stack {
  line-height: 36px;
}
span.fa-stack:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: #2D79AF;
}
span.fa-stack > i:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 14px;
}
#copyright {
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="row footer">
<!-- FOOTER -->
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="copyright">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The icons are just text anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To manually adjust the position of the icons you will have to create the black background separately and then position the icons inside it.

Best way to go forward would be using ul li, as follow

```
<ul class="social_icon">    
     <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx" class="facebook">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/xxxxxx" class="twitter">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="https://in.linkedin.com/xxxxxxxx" class="linkedin">
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
     </li> 
     <li>
        <a href="mailTo:mail@xxxxxxxxxx.com" class="email">
           <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        </a>
     </li> 
</ul>
```

CSS would go something like this:

```
.social_icon {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.social_icon li {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.facebook i {
    position: relative;
    top: xx;
}
```

Comment: wow.. i posted incomplete answer by mistake and got -2 score in 4 minutes.

Comment: I believe it's normal, lots of users post incomplete answer and leave it there. Hopefully users who has downvoted previously will un-downvote when seeing that it improved.

Comment: My suggestion if you post incomplete answers by mistake is to delete immediately. You can always edit the deleted answer and when is completed undelete

Answer (score 1):

the icons are text, it means you can modify them as you would any character.

Just add something like:

```
.fa-linkedin, .fa-envelope-o {
  font-size:12px;  
}
.fa-circle {color:red;}
```

To your css but I would recomend you to add your own class to your icons insteed of overwritting awesome fonts css as in this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tecudgjj/1/)**